# Combining SQL Parameters with external path?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following, which is working just as I would expect:

```
IF '$(EnvName)' LIKE 'Path%'
BEGIN
    :r .\Path\Path1.sql
END
```

What I'm trying to do is:

```
IF '$(EnvName)' LIKE 'Path%'
BEGIN
    :r .\Path\'$(EnvName)'.sql
END
```

But this fails because the result is `.\Path\".sql` - despite the `IF ('$EnvName')` working perfectly fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `:r .\Path\$(EnvName).sql`

Answer (score 0):

SQLCMD variables are like a pre-processor.  You only need to worry about quoting them when the expression expects a quoted value, and `:r` only wants the whole path quoted.

Try:

```
IF '$(EnvName)' LIKE 'Path%'
BEGIN
    :r .\Path\$(EnvName).sql
END
```

Or:

```
IF '$(EnvName)' LIKE 'Path%'
BEGIN
    :r ".\Path\$(EnvName).sql"
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
:SETVAR FilePath ".\Path\"
:SETVAR FileExt ".sql"
IF '$(EnvName)' LIKE 'Path%'
BEGIN
    :r $(FilePath)$(EnvName)$(FileExt)
END
```